# Sharepoint mail enabled library receives csv file, import into list

Tags: csv, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am wondering what the best approach is (if any) to handle this scenario:

I will set up a mail enabled library to which an external party can send emails with a csv file attached.

What i want to do next is, on each received file into this library (or even once a day process them all) use this csv file and import it into a list for easier viewing.

I was thinking to create a custom workflow on item added that opens the csv file and imports it into another list.

Are there better/easier setups?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say an event receiver may be more suitable for the scenario. That way you can capture the CSV file, extract it's contents, and add each line as an item. I use event receivers for a one-hop event, and workflows as mutiple hops (approvals, feedback, etc.).

Here is more on event receivers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx